# Center Section Not Fitting in 3-Column Responsive CSS Layout

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design

I have a 3-column layout that works pretty well:

http://jsfiddle.net/nicorellius/YNyHW/7/

My goal is to add a pre-existing modular unit into the center `div`, the one with class `two-inner`. The markup is like so:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div>  
    <div class="container">       
        <div class="one">
            <div class="one-inner"></div>
        </div>               
        <div class="two">
            <div class="two-inner"></div>
        </div>                       
        <div class="three">
            <div class="three-inner"></div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS can be seen in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicorellius/YNyHW/7/). Part of the modular unit is actually built from some PHP where some data from a database is fetched and displayed. I have some arrays that I'm using for testing that mimic 6 entries and gives the modular unit a 2-wide by 3-tall box layout. My problem is that when I add this unit into the layout above, I get something like the test site below.

The markup for the modular unit is like so:

```
<section class="unit">
    <section class="buttons margin-top-2em">
        <div class="button-fixed-width">
            <button type="button" class="<bootstrap-button>">button 1</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-fixed-width">
            <button type="button" class="<bootstrap-button>">button 2</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-fixed-width">
            <button type="button" class="<bootstrap-button>">button 3</button>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="row">   
        <?php // loop through some arrays to get module unit ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

I've tried various tweaks to try and get it up but the only thing that does it is making the heights of the outer classes `one`, `two`, and `three` close to zero.

Although I've tried changing heights and other bits to get it to fit, I'm still having trouble figuring out why that center `div` won't go up. What am I missing?

The CSS for the `unit` class is in the fiddle. On it's own, it works OK, and I have some breakpoints that collapse it down into a single column. I just cant get passed this part...

**EDIT**

After trying some ideas from @kozlovski5, I am able to get the `div`moving up and down as I need. But there is something going on that is making me uneasy. I'm not too familiar with the `display: table`, `display: table-cell` layout so Im sure I'm missing something. For example, when I add text to the `div`s in question, either the classes `one`, `two`, or `three`, or the inner classes, the adjustments recommended by @kozlovski5 go away. So in other words if I don't use `top: -37.5em;` and just fill the `div`s with text, everything seems to work as it should. It's when I try to model the layout with bordered sections that I get the strange behavior.

I ended up going with floats instead. See test site above for final.

Comment: Try removing the class <bootstrap-button>

Comment: I added that so you would know that it what it is...  It's really the set of button classes that make the button look like it does: `btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block`, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied:

```
div > .modular {
    display: block;
}
```

This seems to solve the problem. Here is an updated jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/YNyHW/4/

OP has provided a test case for his website, so my updated answer is:

```
.two-inner {
    background-color: #cba;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -596px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Ugghhh.. Another Edit

I think the whole `display: table` and `div > div. { display: table-cell;}` is causing this issue and instead of working on patches let's hit the problem head straigh on instead of working on fixes.

Just get rid of the display table etc. And use floats instead here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/YNyHW/6/

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your suggestion and it's not working. I do see it working in the fiddle you provided, but because I pieced together my question without supplying all the code, I'm sure I missed something. I'll try and track it down.

Comment: You could always edit you're question and improve it, maybe link to the test case (website), maybe the next problem you encountered after the given solution etc. But if you found this question useful accept it.

Comment: I posted the test site - could you take a look?

Comment: @nicorellius took a look, see my answer

Comment: So with this edit, I can get the `div` to move up, but this doesn't seem right to me. The outer `div`s are now too tall and if I change remove the heights, the module `div` is not positioned correctly any more. I will accept your answer because it definitely got me out of my rut but it seems there is a better solution somewhere I haven't thought of. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, will keep looking at your problem and will try to find a solution

Comment: @nicorellius see my new edit and use floats instead of display: table

Comment: That works - except for the whole thing needs to be centered... I had originally used a non-`display: table;` layout (eg, floats) and I was getting frustrated so I gave the table layout a try. I prefer floats since I'm more familiar with them but I was stuck. This is much better! Thanks for taking the time to help me.